# Jquery pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, jquery-pagination

I have my code working etc for the pagination  plugin but I have a slight error.

When I add a table above my table which works with the sorter and pagination the pagination does not work. I think it is because that the table above it is taking the all the features and not using them.

So is there a way to define which table to use like using a ID ?

If any one could give an example it would be great.

This is the code I am using

http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js

Comment: can you show us a little bit of code?

Comment: Most probably it will be an error with your selector.

Comment: were would the selector in this code be ?  http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js

Comment: If you showed some code, we'd be able to help better. As this question is now, we can't answer definitively.

Answer (score 0):

You would define which table to apply the tablesorter to like this:

Assuming you have two tables, 
`<table id="table1">..</table>` and `<table id="table2">..</table>` and you want to apply the table sorter only to the second table, use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table2").tablesorter(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for pagination its taken form https://convertintowordpress.com/simple-jquery-table-pagination-code/

```
function pagination(){
var req_num_row=10;
var $tr=jQuery('tbody tr');
var total_num_row=$tr.length;
var num_pages=0;
if(total_num_row % req_num_row ==0){
    num_pages=total_num_row / req_num_row;
}
if(total_num_row % req_num_row >=1){
    num_pages=total_num_row / req_num_row;
    num_pages++;
    num_pages=Math.floor(num_pages++);
}
for(var i=1; i<=num_pages; i++){
    jQuery('#pagination').append(""+i+"");
}
$tr.each(function(i){
    jQuery(this).hide();
    if(i+1 <= req_num_row){
        $tr.eq(i).show();
}

});
jQuery('#pagination a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $tr.hide();
    var page=jQuery(this).text();
    var temp=page-1;
    var start=temp*req_num_row;
    for(var i=0; i< req_num_row; i++){
        $tr.eq(start+i).show();
    }
});
}
```